# GASでLINE MessagingAPIを使った際に出る401エラーの対処法を知りたい

Tags: api, google-apps-script, line

LINEdevelopersにて、**Webhookの検証**を実行すると、**ボットサーバーから200以外のHTTPステータスコードが返されました**というエラーになる問題で困っています。
原因または解決策をご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんか。

### 私の行った手順は以下です。

1. [LINEのBot開発 超入門（前編） ゼロから応答ができるまで](https://qiita.com/nkjm/items/38808bbc97d6927837cd#channel%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)を参考に、Channelを作成する。
2. [Google Apps ScriptでLINE BOTつくったら30分で動かせた件](https://qiita.com/hakshu/items/55c2584cf82718f47464#gas%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)のコードをコピペ。
3. 2と同じ記事の内容にしたがってGASでサービスの公開
4. LINE developper でWebhookの設定まで行う、[検証](https://gyazo.com/aca1b3aeabfef86f4881354a206eaabb)を実行

すると、以下のような結果になりました。

**エラー**

ボットサーバーから200以外のHTTPステータスコードが返されました

[image: 画像]

ちなみに、エラーのステータスコードは**401**でした。

[image: 画像]

私は検証が上手くいくと思いました。
なぜなら、『Google Apps ScriptでLINE BOTつくったら30分で動かせた件』の手順通りに行ってみたからです。

原因を確かめるため、以下のような手順を行ってみました

(a) [Messaging API のドキュメント](https://developers.line.biz/ja/reference/messaging-api/#status-codes)を確認

> **”有効なチャンネルアクセストークンが指定されていません”**

(b) LINE Devaloppers でチャネルアクセストークンを確認

> Messaging APIを呼び出すときに使用するチャネルアクセストークンです。このチャネルアクセストークンは期限切れになりません。新しいチャネルアクセストークンを発行したり、既存のチャネルアクセストークンを置き換える場合は、「発行」をクリックします。

上記の表記があるが、再発行をしてもう一度GASでWebhookの設定,
更新→公開URLを LINE Devaloppers に貼り付け

結果に変化はありませんでした。

### 聞きたいこと

LINE側で他にするべき認証の手続きのようなものがあるのでしょうか？
[https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Client_error_responses)

また、考えられる原因として

- LINEdevelopersにおいて、何か設定をしていない
- GASのコードに問題がある

などあると思いますが、**401エラーがどこの部分ででいるのか**知りたいです。

### GASのコード

（Google Apps ScriptでLINE BOTつくったら30分で動かせた件より）

```js
// LINE developersのメッセージ送受信設定に記載のアクセストークン
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '----------------------------------------------------;

function doPost(e) {
  // WebHookで受信した応答用Token
  var replyToken = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].replyToken;
  // ユーザーのメッセージを取得
  var userMessage = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].message.text;
  // 応答メッセージ用のAPI URL
  var url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply';

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
    },
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'replyToken': replyToken,
      'messages': [{
        'type': 'text',
        'text': userMessage + 'ンゴ',
      }],
    }),
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'content': 'post ok'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

なお、私の環境は以下の通りです。
macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: 回答される方へ https://teratail.com/questions/227966

Comment: というか上記リンク先で解決済みとのこと。

Answer (score 1):

[Google Apps Script側の設定でパブリックアクセス可能にする](https://teratail.com/questions/227966)必要があります。

---

これで問題は解消しますが、LINE以外からのメッセージも受信してしまうので、実際のbot実装ではLINEが送信したものかの判定が必要なります。

- [署名を検証する](https://developers.line.biz/ja/reference/messaging-api/#signature-validation) - Messaging APIリファレンス
- 公式SDKの[`validate-signature.ts`](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-nodejs/blob/v6.8.3/lib/validate-signature.ts)
- (最近見かけた実例として)[こちらの質問文](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42496/2808)中の `validate_signature` 関数